# Joomla module php error?

Tags: php, joomla

I've got a situation with a Joomla 3 module. It looks like it's working as it's supposed to work, but the content is not exactly what I need.

In this code something is wrong:

`<input type="submit" class="button" value="<?php echo JText::_('Submit'); ?>" class="submit" />`

I also tried to use a few PHP code testers, but 3 out of 4 say there's no problem. One of them said to me there's an unexpected "<" in this line. Anyway, that's one thing that's false (correct me if I'm wrong).

Anyway, this code should be showing in the content button "Submit", but it shows no value, only the module name.

Any ideas, guys?

Comment: [It's not as simple as you are thinking it is](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_language_management). You will need to create language files.

Comment: Ohh.. Can you please send me your module installer ? so i can look on it and can help you to solve issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please add name="MyButton" attribute in input, and assign simply value="Submit" and than test it.

and yes keep only one class attribute :)

hope it will work :)

`<input type="submit" name="MyButton" class="button" value="Submit" />`

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately your solution isn't working, still the same problem. :/

Comment: Ohh.. Can you please send me your module installer ? so i can look on it and can help you to solve issue.